# disable right click without js and css

Tags: javascript, css, html, right-click

This is a random Chinese website `http://www.soap-china.com/index.asp`

I noticed that right click is disabled. I always have JavaScript off, so I started delete node by node, css line by line in Firebag, but didn't find out what is disabling right click.

How does it work?

This is not first time I see this, so I am curious about this trick.

Comment: Wow, that’s really something. I would have guessed `pointer-events: none` (since selection doesn’t work either), but it’s not that. Flash, maybe, but that’s not everywhere. Good question!

Comment: There’s the `onselectstart="return false"`, but that is, of course, JavaScript…

Comment: Seams like NoScript bag, asked here: https://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=20026

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is done with javascript.

I have disabled javascript and I can right-click. It disables with:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
document.oncontextmenu =new Function("return false;")
</script>    
<body onselectstart="return false">
```

There might be an issue with your browser, the site is online for me.

Comment: Yep. That is strange, but NoScript doesn't stop this script. So it is NoScript bag. I should check default javascript off.

Answer (score 30):

On the body Tag do this:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Well, simple and effective. Great answer.

Comment: If your body does not cover the whole screen and you want to disable right click on the whole screen, use this with the html tag. `<html lang="en" oncontextmenu="return false"> ... </html>`. Helped me in a Chromium Kiosk with Raspberry Pi OS Buster.

Comment: This is technically using javascript

Answer (score 6):

You can use `user-select` in CSS on any elements you don't want to be clicked on. Variants are needed for some older browsers though. As follows;

```
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.oncontextmenu =new Function("return false;")
document.onselectstart =new Function("return false;")
</script>
```

Good luck.

Comment: contexmenu means the right click menu, select means text select. Right?

Answer (score -4):

Or you can always do this simple method

add the oncontextmenu handler to it as

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

Comment: You don't need to copy someone else's answer below and post it as your answer.